# How to run the PowerShell script through PowerShell ISE which was opened by Solution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

Windows 7 x64. MS Visual Studio 2013.

I included PowerShell scripts for batch building of my project.
At first, I set the necessary execution policy (run with admin rights):

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

    Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic. Do you want to change the execution
policy?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

I reloaded my computer even. I run my scripts through its context menu in the Solution Explorer:

[image]

But when I try to run it, in the PowerShell ISE I get this message:

> the execution of scripts is disabled on this system

[image]

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two PowerShell, one 32 bit version and one 64 bit version:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

In both folders you will find a powershell.exe and a powershell_ise.exe and you will find out when you change the execution policy in one location, it doesn't affect the other version. Make sure you set both to the desired state and then try again!